# Accessing onenote via API MS graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I've read lots of docs and different posts, but I can't get the right access token to read my own OneNote via api.

- I have MS account and app in azure portal.
- In graph-explorer I CAN read my OneNote.
- If I copy access token from graph-explorer, then my code works fine.

BUT:

- If I request access token from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tried 'common' or my tenant_id here}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
  then it does not work:

`The OAuth token provided does not have the necessary scopes to complete the request. Please make sure you are including one or more of the following scopes: Notes.ReadWrite.All,Notes.Read.All`

- I created app in azure portal and gave it all read permissions, which I found ( for both one-note and ms graph APIs, both delegated and application... just for test) and generated secret
- I'm trying following request:

```
token_request_data = {
    'client_id': 'id from my app',     # also tried 'common'
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',  # other scopes cause errors
    'client_secret': 'secret from my app',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
}
```

Perhaps somebody could give me a clue what I'm doing wrong ? :)

Sample request via graph explorer:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my_username}@outlook.com/onenote/sections`

[Permissions in app (azure portal) screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnSly.png)

[Permissions in graph explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA5WS.png)

Comment: Have you added application permissions 'Notes.Read.All' in Azure Application. As you are using client_credential grant type you need to give application permissions. Also share the graph call which you are using in graph explorer. Also share the screenshot of the permissions that you added in Azure AD Application

Comment: Hello, I added the screenshots and sample request at the end of my Question post.

Comment: Notes.Read.All and Notes.readWrite.All are valid for Work or school accounts only. Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#remarks-15).

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity You should make that the answer :)

Comment: Sure, Thanks for reminding @juunas :)-

Comment: Thank you, So it seems i can only have 'Notes.Read'. I won't be able to read my OneNote via API without logging in via browser ?

Comment: Yes, as of now you cannot do that. If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Notes.Read.All` and `Notes.readWrite.All` are valid for Work or school accounts only. Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#remarks-15).